# Retrieve Value of a single column

Tags: php, sql, json, api

I need to retrieve data from a single column and put in an API (Json), but for some reason I get the title from the column as well.

```
$sql = "SELECT workingJson FROM dataTable";
```

I assumed it would be like `workingJson.Value`, but no luck.

Here is the API.php

```
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT column1 FROM database";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit per your comments:

To just return the values and not the keys in PHP, you could change your code to this:

```
// Loop through each row in the result set
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    // Add value to array
    array_push($resultArray, $row->column1);
}
```

You have no need for `$tempArray` in this case.

Comment: @WillemMassoels I have edited my answer per your comments.

Comment: @WillemMassoels I think you need to provide more debugging information then.  What I have shown would return a JSON representation like `["somevalue", "someothervalue", ...]`  When you say "no luck" what does that mean?  Where in either your server-side or client-side code execution does the execution vary from what you expect?

Comment: HI Mike, I updated initial question with an image of the database.
In column.Value 'workingJson' I can retrieve the Json from an Quiz module in wordpress... I corrected the API but I got a blank page as results, maybe I did wrong ( as you can tell, I have never done this :p)

Comment: @WillemMassoels I don't know what any of your additional information has to do with with the problem at hand, other than you would just need to change `$row->column1` in my answer to `$row->workingJson` if you are using that column name in your select. That is why I said you need to debug.  Perhaps your MySQL connection isn't working, perhaps your client side code is incorrect.  I don't know without further debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all results and after doing a traitment :

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT column1 FROM database";


if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {

    //get all fields :
    $finfo = $result->fetch_fields();

    foreach ($finfo as $val) {
        $resultArray[] = $val->column1;
    }
    $result->close();
}

// Finally, output the results without encode because is also in json format:
echo '{'. implode(','.chr(10), $resultArray) .'}';

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: thanks Ilyas, is the echo ($resultArray);

$mysqli->close(); the correct syntax to echo the array in a plain text... at the moment I just get "Array" as result.

Comment: oooh yes I forget this, try now with implode !

Comment: Thanks Ilyas for all your help.